# Subtracting DB values via php

Tags: php, subtraction

I am trying to subtract values of a db table $activationFee from a users total balance . How may i add the subtraction in the code below:

```html
<div class="number">
    <strong>
        <?php echo $settings->currency; ?>
        <?php BalanceSystem($user_id); ?>
    </strong>
</div>
```

```
function BalanceSystem($user_id){
 $user_bank = DB::table('bank')->where('userid', $user_id)->first();
 echo $user_bank->balance;
}
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

I tried `<?php BalanceSystem($user_id) - $activationFee ; ?>` but did not work ... hides

Comment: There is no subtraction present in this code.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please update your question with all relevant code, expected and current output. I can't see BalanceSystem class/function, $activationFee or any subtraction in this code.

Comment: Hi and thank you for responding. i am looking for help on how to add the subtraction to the code

Comment: @Robert currently we don't know how your variables are setup and without more information we can't assist you.

Comment: Something like `$currentBalance -= $activationFee;`?

Comment: Yes @Barmar ... I tried <?php BalanceSystem($user_id) - $activationFee ; ?> but did not work ... *hides*

Comment: That won't work if `BalanceSystem()` echoes the balance. You need something that assigns the balance to a variable so you can subtract it.

Comment: Can you include the `BalanceSystem` source code so we can see what it is you're dealing with?

Comment: @El_Vanja ... ```function BalanceSystem($user_id){
  $user_bank = DB::table('bank')->where('userid', $user_id)->first();
  echo $user_bank->balance;
}```

Comment: Just as Barmar suggested - you can't subtract from an echoed value. You need the function to return the value so you can do some handling with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I managed to solve it:

```
    function BalanceSystem($user_id){
      $user_bank = DB::table('bank')->where('userid', $user_id)->first();
      $total = $user_bank->balance - 100;
      echo $total;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not echo inside a function, it will prevent situations like this, where you try to substract a value to an output.

```
<div class="number">
    <strong>
        <?php echo $settings->currency; ?>
        <?php echo BalanceSystem($user_id); ?>
    </strong>
</div>
function BalanceSystem($user_id){
 $user_bank = DB::table('bank')->where('userid', $user_id)->first();
 return $user_bank->balance;
}

//Substract
<?php echo (BalanceSystem($user_id) - $activationFee); ?>
```